# Saving user selection when contentEditable=false

Tags: javascript

I have included a simple homemade WYSIWYG editor into my HTML Javascript App by using a contentEditable DIV (let's call this EDITDIV) and a series of edit buttons in another DIV. Although far from brilliant it works for me and my users.

My problem is whenever I need to fix the text in EDITDIV which I do by simply setting contentEditable=false, I still want to allow the app users to be able select some of their previously editable text in EDITDIV and perform not edit operations on it, e.g. to use it as a search string.

To do this the users need to be able to select some of the text in EDITDIV and then click outside of EDITDIV. At this point the selection is no more. My question is how do I save the selection to use later on. I could do this every time the selection changes, or at the point when the focus on EDITDIV is lost. I tried both techniques. I cannot find an event (e.g. onselect, onselectionchange) that worked reliably for the first method and for the second method, setting contentEditable to false stops the focus, so the onblur event never happens.

Help much appreciated.

Comment: Can you show the several Code-fragments?

Comment: not easily. I am not sure it is a coding issue. It is a knowledge issue (my lack of it). Simple question, what event fires when user selects text in a contentEditable div when contentEditable is set to false.

Comment: I should have been clearer. This works in Chrome, but not in Mobile Safari on the iPad.

Comment: would appear that onselectionchange does the trick for Mobile Safari